# Как реализовать смену фотографии по клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Есть меню, которое меняет меняет фон, так же нужно поменять лого, в моём же варианте оно меняется только 1 раз при первом клике, надо чтобы замена была постоянной, что нужно исправить?

```
let teemsImg = ["imgs/logo.png", "imgs/darkLogo.png"];

function changeImg() {
  for(let i=0; i<teemsImg.length; i++){
    logoImg.src = teemsImg[i];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считайте количество кликов и в зависимости от этого выводите нужное изображение

```js
let teemsImg = ["imgs/logo.png", "imgs/darkLogo.png"];
let itemSelect = 0;
let logoImg = {}
function changeImg() {
  if (itemSelect === teemsImg.length - 1) {
    itemSelect = 0;
    logoImg.src = teemsImg[0];
  } else {
    itemSelect++
    logoImg.src = teemsImg[itemSelect];
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  changeImg();
  console.log(logoImg)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я в начале не понял к чему тут цикл, но когда убрал его и забиндил функцию на ивент нажатия всё заработало.